# Jgroups multicast file transfer

Tags: java, multicast, jgroups

I try to do a multicast file tranfer with jgroups. It works when I put a sleep between each messages. When I remove this sleep, my received file has the same size but it is not openable (order is maybe not respected).

I read my file with FileInputStream and I send it cutted in severals messages in the good order (Only one sender). I use NAKACK to assume reliable and ordered messages.

For testing I'm using a 100MB image for transfer.

How can I know what is going wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried with a text file, the order is not good.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange as JGroups NakAck should respect order of delivery.
You might want to check http://code.google.com/p/fast-cast/. However it might be that you need to write a small service splitting files >30MB into pieces.